# Get all users in ActiveDirectory in different OU by powershell

Tags: powershell

I know how to use Get-ADUser for one OU but how can I expand it for multiple OUs?

```
import-module activedirectory
$Path = 'OU=usertest,dc=a,dc=b,dc=com'
$NumberOfUsersinAD =  (Get-ADUser -SearchBase $Path –filter * ).count 
$ADUsers = Get-ADUser -Searchbase $Path -Filter *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single query can only have one `SearchBase`, but you can issue multiple queries if you like:

```
$Domain      = 'dc=a,dc=b,dc=com'
# Create array of OU paths
$OUsToSearch = @(
  "OU=usertest1,$Domain",
  "OU=usertest2,$Domain",
  "OU=Deeply,OU=Nested,OU=usertest1,$Domain"
)

# Create empty array 
$ADUsers = @()

# Loop through OUs and search for users
foreach($Path in $OUsToSearch){
    $ADUsers += Get-ADUser -SearchBase $Path -Filter *
}

# Count users (no need for a separate query)
$NumberOfADUsers = $ADUsers.Count
```

Comment: Thanks. It wokrs. Just two questions: can you please Explian what $ADUsers = @() does?  How about if we have 30 OU, should I type them one by one?

Comment: @frhling1 I've updated the answer with comments. What do you mean "type them one by one"? If you want to search through *all* OU's, just specify the domain as the `SearchBase`